# Is there a peculiarity for z-indexes and borders that I've never heard of?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use margin and z-index(es) to create a line either side of some text, but the z-indexes don't seem to be ordering the elements like I expected.  Ultimately I'd like to set the text background to white and just have a line showing either side.  I can get the line to go behind the box, but not between the box and the text.  Can anyone shed some light for me?  I'm tearing my hair out and I don't have much.

```css
.thebox {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.thebox h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #666;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 10;    
}

.thebox .theline {
 border-top: solid 1px black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 19%;
 z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="thebox">
    <h1>This is my title text.  I'm hoping that it should end up with a line either side, but not overwriting it.</h1>
    <div class="theline"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the position attribute and switched order and should be okay now :

http://jsfiddle.net/4cw9ns8q/2/

```
.thebox .theline {
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  top: 19%;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  You need to set `position: relative` on the various elements in order for `z-index` to have an effect.  Otherwise,  you were on the right track.

```css
.thebox {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.thebox h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #666;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;    
}

.thebox .theline {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="thebox">
    <h1>This is my title text.  I'm hoping that it should end up with a line 
        either side, but not overwriting it.</h1>
    <div class="theline"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You nee to add position absolute to your h1 as well:

```
.thebox {
background-color: white;
color: black;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
z-index: 1;
```

}

```
.thebox h1 {
text-align: center;
background-color: #666;
margin-right: 100px;
margin-left: 100px;
font-size: 16px;
z-index: 10; 
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
```

}

```
.thebox .theline {
border-top: solid 1px black;
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 39%;
z-index: 5;
```

}

Default position value is static, and index-z works only on elements with non-static position